# Why is Innosetup not installing registry keys?

Tags: windows, registry, inno-setup

I have the following in my script:

```
Root: "HKCU"; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\Company.Tool"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "Manifest"; ValueData: "file:///{code:GetRegistryData}/tool.vsto|vstolocal"; Flags: createvalueifdoesntexist uninsdeletekey; Permissions: admins-full
Root: "HKCU"; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\Company.Tool"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "Description"; ValueData: "description"; Flags: createvalueifdoesntexist uninsdeletekey; Permissions: admins-full
Root: "HKCU"; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\Company.Tool"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "FriendlyName"; ValueData: "friendly name"; Flags: createvalueifdoesntexist uninsdeletekey; Permissions: admins-full
Root: "HKCU"; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\Company.Tool"; ValueType: dword; ValueName: "LoadBehavior"; ValueData: "3"; Flags: createvalueifdoesntexist uninsdeletekey; Permissions: admins-full

[Code]
function GetRegistryData(Value: string): string;
begin
    Result := ExpandConstant('{app}');
    StringChangeEx(Result, '\', '/', True);
end;
```

I was running this as an admin and had no issues whatsoever (works on my machine!).  Now that I'm attempting to run it as a standard user, everything else is being installed, but the registry keys are not being installed.  I have UAC turned on and validating with an admin account for the install to run.

Anything else I can check on to get registry keys installed?

Comment: My crystal ball says that it actually works but your "validation" is flawed. Since you use a different user account so look at different HKCU keys.  Double-check with SysInternals' Process Monitor, you see the installer writing the keys.

Comment: There is no _failed to set permissions on registry key_ items in the log.  I'm also using this line as well to no avail

`PrivilegesRequired=admin`

Comment: @HansPassant Sure enough!  So how do I avoid this and install keys for the user that's a non-admin user?  This piece of software is going to be licensed per user, so I'd rather not do a global registry key if I can avoid it...